# Locate the .desktop file for a special menu item

Tags: package-management, filenames, debugging, .desktop

There are various reasons why **orphaned menu items** can **remain after package removal** and need to be fixed in the package.

In order to investigate the bug, it can help to see the exact path of the `.desktop` file. Unfortunately there are several folders where these files can be and **one can not see from the filename directly which file belongs to an menu item**.

On this test machine, a broken Thunderbird package did not remove its icon on package removal (the picture shows a Mate Desktop screenshot from an application menu with a sketch of the information needed):

[image: a broken Thunderbird package missed to remove its icon]

**I would like to see which .desktop files are responsible for each menu item.**

Is there for example a tool, which can **show the full path** when hovering the menu items?

**Edit:** I am not looking for the list of paths where `.desktop` files are stored on a special distribution. I am looking for the path of one special (or all) menu item.

Comment: Which distribution are you working on ?

Comment: @dubis I work on Gentoo packages, but I am interested also in a solution for other major distributions like the *buntu/debian family. This would be interesting for the other readers too. I saw these bugs on several distributions already.

Comment: I'm sure is depend of the distribution and desktop environment like in KDE  you're able to edit your own menu. I've 3 pathes on my Kubuntu  `/usr/share/applications/` ;  `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/` and`/home/user/.local/share/applications/` where `. desktop` files are located

Comment: The paths may differ, but the path is what I am looking for. So it should be the same procedure for all distributions. (It may vary with the desktop). But lets take Mate/Gnome/KDE so that we do not over complicate it.